# Binding and Selecting Bootstrap Drop-down dynamically in Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I was trying for dynamic bootstrap drop-down i.e getting the values and populating from list(list will have id and name) and when selected the option from drop-down getting the selected option id in Model,

While getting I need to get the drop-down option selected by the the option model is having the Id,
Cannot find perfect solution any where
Can any one put a light on this??

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/td2nz/) I think it will answer you..

Comment: @MoshFeu That's what I was saying i need a pure Bootstrap drop down, the select is HTML and it will change from browser to browser

Comment: OK. You can use [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview